# dragon naturally speaking footnote

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking, footnote

I use Dragon Nat. Sp. version 13.

How do I put in a footnote indicator, I. e. a little number right after the relevant word, slightly up? I can't find one command.

Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I put in a footnote indicator, a little number right after the word, slightly up?

You need a superscript.

> [image]

Source [Dictating numbers](http://www.nuance.com/products/help/dragon/dragon-for-mac/enx/Content/Dictating/Dictating_numbers.htm)